# Find a cyclic subgroup of order 4 in $A_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I need to find a subgroup of $A_8$ of order 4 that is cyclic. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Thought: Of course a 4-cycle has order four, but sadly a 4-cycle is an odd permutation.  Could you multiply it by something so the result is an even permutation but the order is still 4?

Comment: Can I multiply it by (1)?

Comment: Since $(1)$ is an even permutation, the product would still be odd.

Comment: does (12) work? How about its being cyclic?

Comment: $(12)$ might work, depending on what your $4$-cycle is.

Comment: How about its being cyclic tho?

Comment: If you iterate any single element of a group, the result is a cyclic subgroup.

Comment: How come can I do that?

Comment: A cyclic group consists of all the powers of the generating element. So, after you find an even element of order $4$, calculate its powers. Those form the cyclic subgroup of order $4$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find an element of $A_8$ of order $4$. What permutations of order $4$ do you know?

Comment: $(34)(45)(56)(67)$?

Comment: No, this premutation has order $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some details on paw88789's answer:

- $(1234)$ has order $4$ but is an odd permutation.
- $(1234)(ab)$ is an even permutation that will have order $4$ if $(1234)$ and $(ab)$ commute.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha = (1234) (56)$

Recall the thm Order of a Permutation: "The order of a permutation of a finite ser written in a disjoint cycle form is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles."

Thus:

$|\alpha| = |(1234)(56)|$

$|\alpha| = lcm(4,2)$

$|\alpha| = 4$

Hence we can see that $|<\alpha>| = |\alpha| = 4$